# HTTP Request Response in Different Flow

Tags: http, request, mule, esb, mule-studio

currently I am working with Mule and need to do something like this:

**-- FLOW UPDATED --**

[image: Flow]

Where the http endpoint is request-response (not one way). I mean, I would like to query the request on my http in RequestFlow and get the response from the http in ServiceResponse.

How to do so? Thanks for your help.

**-- XML Configuration ADDED --** (**Request-Reply Tag Updated**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:jdbc-ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms" xmlns:wmq="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns:data-mapper="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper/current/mule-data-mapper.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/wmq/current/mule-wmq-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc/current/mule-jdbc-ee.xsd">
    <custom-transformer name="StringToNameString" class="de.fraport.sources.StringtoAusweis" doc:name="Java"/>
    <wmq:connector name="WMQ" hostName="localhost" port="1414" queueManager="localmanager" validateConnections="true" doc:name="WMQ" ccsId="819"/>
    <data-mapper:config name="json_to_xml" transformationGraphPath="json_to_xml.grf" doc:name="json_to_xml"/>

    <flow name="RequestFlow" doc:name="RequestFlow">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="uebermittleAusweisdaten" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <expression-filter expression="#[message.payload !='/favicon.ico']" doc:name="Expression"/>
        <set-variable variableName="id" value="#[message.id]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="json_to_xml" doc:name="JSON To XML">
            <data-mapper:input-arguments>
                <data-mapper:input-argument key="id">#[flowVars['id']]</data-mapper:input-argument>
            </data-mapper:input-arguments>
        </data-mapper:transform>
        <mulexml:xslt-transformer maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" xsl-file="D:\Workspace\soaptest\mobako.sender.xsl" doc:name="XSLT" encoding="ISO8859-1"/>
        <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer  doc:name="DOM to XML" outputEncoding="ISO8859-1"/>
        <wmq:outbound-endpoint queue="LSMH.ZKSEAP.SERVICEBUS" connector-ref="WMQ" doc:name="ZKSEAP IN" encoding="ISO8859-1" />
        <request-reply storePrefix="mainFlow">
        <wmq:outbound-endpoint queue="LSMH.ZKSEAP.SERVICEBUS" connector-ref="WMQ" doc:name="ZKSEAP IN" encoding="ISO8859-1" correlationId="#[message.id]"/>
        <wmq:inbound-endpoint queue="ZKSEAP.LSMH.SERVICEBUS" connector-ref="WMQ" doc:name="ZKSEAP OUT" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    </request-reply>
        <http:response-builder doc:name="HTTP Response Builder"/>
    </flow>
    <flow name="ServiceResponse" doc:name="ServiceResponse">
        <wmq:inbound-endpoint queue="ZKSEAP.LSMH.SERVICEBUS" connector-ref="WMQ" doc:name="ZKSEAP OUT" encoding="UTF-8"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

**-- Error Update --**

After I changed the flow and use reply-response routing message, i try to debug the flow. And I found something weird. When the debugger reach the

> request-reply

component, it will automatically goes back to

> expression

component (looping). How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your goal, you need to:

- Make the HTTP endpoint in `RequestFlow` a `request-response` one,
- Use a [`request-reply` routing message processor](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-RequestReply) to perform the asynchronous operations over WMQ while blocking `RequestFlow` until a response comes from `ZKSEAP OUT`.

Comment: Can you please give an example about how to do it with wmq? Because when I tried to do so, I got following error:

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'wmq:inbound-endpoint'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor}' is expected.

Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and show the XML config you have that gives this error. Don't forget to redact any private config bit (passwords for ex :))

Comment: hi @david, I have edited my question. do you have any idea about that problem? thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you are calling the `uebermittleAusweisdaten` HTTP endpoint in the `request-reply` router? I thought you wanted to perform a queue interaction there, i.e. have the WMQ outbound request queue and WMQ inbound response queue in the `request-reply`.

Comment: I have tried to do as you said (mq outbound and inbound) on the request-reply, but  I don't get any response. Let me edit my question again to show you what changed I have made. Thanks

Comment: You've left a `wmq:outbound-endpoint` before the `request-reply`: it should be gone. Also `ServiceResponse` has `wmq:inbound-endpoint queue="ZKSEAP.LSMH.SERVICEBUS"` which will potentially consume the response that is expected by the same endpoint in the `request-reply`. Not sure what you're trying to achieve here but this can not work. The `request-reply` element should be the only one consuming the response queue.

Comment: what I want to achieve is sending the response from wmq:inbound-endpoint queue="ZKSEAP.LSMH.SERVICEBUS" to http. FYI, the "ZKSEAP.LSMH.SERVICEBUS" queue can only be used for read and the LSMH.ZKSEAP.SERVICEBUS queue can only be used for write. Then how to do so? Your help is so much appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear: when you say that you want to send the response from the WMQ endpoint to HTTP, do you mean to use it as the response for the inbound HTTP endpoint or to call another HTTP endpoint?

Comment: I want to use it as response.

Comment: OK then that's fine, the `request-reply` will block until the response comes on `ZKSEAP.LSMH.SERVICEBUS` (with the right correlation ID). After that, the in-flight message can be used for building the response.